# Web scraping - Python script return [] / None

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get the simple python code to return mobile name mentioned in the site. but it did not work. please suggest me if in good direction.

```
import requests
from bs4
import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/offers-list/new-launches?screen=dynamic&pk=themeViews%3DNewLaunches%3ADesktopView~widgetType%3DdealCard~contentType%3Dneo&wid=5.dealCard.OMU&otracker=clp_omu_New+Launches_mobiles_4'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

mobileN = soup.find_all("div", {
  "class",
  "iUmrbN"
})

for mo in mobileN:
  print mo.text.strip()
```

Error/warning is like

```
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:335: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  SNIMissingWarning
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:133: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:181: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 63 of the file C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\PyScripter\remserver.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})

to this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))
>>>
```

Comment: `To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:`... Read that

Comment: Sorry ..! I re-post it again

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import urllib
import bs4 

req = urllib.request.Request('https://www.flipkart.com/offers-list/new-launches?screen=dynamic&pk=themeViews%3DNewLaunches%3ADesktopView~widgetType%3DdealCard~contentType%3Dneo&wid=5.dealCard.OMU&otracker=clp_omu_New+Launches_mobiles_4')
content = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

for link in soup.findAll("a"):
    print(link.get("href"))
```

Comment: It gives Error saying  object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: Try import urllib.request

Comment: Are u using Windows or LInux?

Comment: I am using window10 with Pyscripter.

Comment: Then I can not help you,I am using Ubuntu 16.04.